# What is the difference between the outputs of these two programs and why?

Tags: c++, static

Here are two programs. Both of them have a function fun() whose return type is reference to an integer. Only the difference between two functions is that in one function x is declared as static int while in other it is not. The output to the first question is 10 and the output to the second question is 30. How?

Program 1:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int &fun()
{
    int x = 10;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout << fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Program 2:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int &fun()
{
    static  int x = 10;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout << fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first program invokes undefined behavior, the second one does not.

Comment: what is undefined behaviour? can u tell me why is the difference in the output of both the programs?

Comment: You can google "undefined behavior" and you will understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Program 1: you return a reference to a variable which ceases to exist as soon as the function returns, then store the value 30 to that non-existing variable, which may or may not crash your machine.  Regardless, the following call to fun() reinitializes a local variable "x" and returns it.

Program 2: A static variable at function scope is kind of like a global variable that's only accessible to that function.  You return a reference to that static (which still exists), and set its value.  When you call the function again, the static still has the value you assigned to it.